# Multiple serial animations in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit, scntranscaction

I want to be able to run multiple animations, one after another, in SceneKit. I've implemented a function which runs one animation like so:

```
fileprivate func animateMove(_ move: Move) {
    print("Animate move started " + move.identifier)

    // I am creating rotateNode
    let rotateNode = SCNNode()
    rotateNode.eulerAngles.x = CGFloat.pi
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(rotateNode)

    // Then I am selecting nodes which I want to rotate
    nodesToRotate = ...

    // Then I am adding the nodes to rotate node
    _ = nodesToRotate.map { rotateNode.addChildNode($0) }

    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = move.animationDuration

    SCNTransaction.completionBlock = {
        rotateNode.enumerateChildNodes { node, _ in
            node.transform = node.worldTransform
            node.removeFromParentNode()
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        }
        rotateNode.removeFromParentNode()
        print("Animate move finished " + move.identifier)
    }
    SCNTransaction.commit()
}
```

And then I've tried to run multiple serial animations like so:

```
    func animateMoves(_ moves: [Move]) {
        for (index, move) in moves.enumerated() {
            perform(#selector(animateMove(_:)), 
            with: move, 
            afterDelay: TimeInterval(Double(index) * move.duration)
        }
    }
```

Everything is animating but the animations don't run in a serial manner. Animations start and finish in unpredictable time. 
Sample logs from debugger:

```
Animate move started 1
Animate move started 2
Animate move finished 1
Animate move finished 2
Animate move started 3
Animate move finished 3
```

I realise that my approach isn't the best, but only in that way I was able to achieve almost working animations.

I know that there is a SCNAction class available. Maybe I should make many actions within one transaction? If so, could someone explain to me how exactly SCNTransactions work and why the completion SCNTransaction's completion block fires in unpredictable time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use **SCNAction.sequence()**:

```
class func sequence([SCNAction])
```

*Creates an action that runs a collection of actions sequentially*

```
let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([action1, action2, action3]) // will be executed one by one

let node = SCNNode()
node.runAction(sequence, completionHandler:nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following @Oleh Zayats' answer I've tried to implement my case using SCNAction.sequence(_:) method, but the problem was that I needed completion handler to be fired after every completed subaction in order to be able to remove the nodes from rotationNode.

After a couple of hours of struggling I've ended up with quite a nice solution and it worked like a charm.

Namely:

I've made a function rotateAction which looks something like this:

```
func rotateAction(with move: Move, from rotateNode: SCNNode) -> SCNAction {

    let preAction = SCNAction.run { (rotateNode) in
        // all the pre action setup like choosing nodes to rotate
    }

    let action = SCNAction.rotate(by: -move.angle, around: vector, duration: move.animationDuration)

    let postAction = SCNAction.run { (rotateNode) in
        // completion handler for each action 
    }

    return SCNAction.sequence([preAction, action, postAction])
}
```

Then I was able to write a function to be able to run multiple animations one after another:

```
func animateRotateMoves(_ moves: [Move]) {
    let rotateNode = SCNNode()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(rotateNode)

    var actions: [SCNAction] = []
    for move in moves {
        let action = rotateAction(with: move, from: rotateNode)
        actions.append(action)
    }
    actions.append(SCNAction.removeFromParentNode())
    let sequence = SCNAction.sequence(actions)
    rotateNode.runAction(sequence)
}
```